# Perl regex to find specific hex character on snort

Tags: regex, perl, snort

I'm pretty new to the Perl Regex and wanted to know, how I can write a Regex that would match a specific hex character, for example `0x90`.
I have tried: `"[\x90]"`,`"\x90"` but these seem not to work..
I using snort and need to make a rule that will find the `0x90` char in the text:

```
Alert TCP any any -> any any (msg: "Possible exploit"; pcre:"\x90"; sid:15444552;)
```

This is what I have tried but snort gives me an error:

```
ERROR: newRules.conf Line 9 => unable to parse pcre regex "\x90"
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start and end with an slash `/`. In your case, `pcre:"\x90"` Should be `pcre:"/\x90/"`

For further information take a look [here](http://manual.snort.org/node32.html#SECTION004523000000000000000)